# Capturing logs and making it into a textfile

Tags: c#, string, methods, parameter-passing, text-files

I have the condition below where the Logger() captures the appropriate texts that will be used as logs, I want these logs to be made into a text file.

---

```
try{
      if (mailRecipient.Resolved)
      {
        mail.Send();
        Logger("Email send to : " + recipients);
      }
      else
      {
        Logger("There is no such record in your address book.");
      }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
      Logger("An exception is occured in the code of add-in.");
      Logger(ex.Message);
      Logger("Stack Trace :" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
```

---

After having the text file, I will have to get it from its path and add it as an attachment to the function below.

---

```
logFile = //path of the text file;

mail.Attachments.Add(logFile);
```

---

**How can I capture these logs and make it into a textfile, then use that textfile as an attachment?**

Comment: seems like you'd need a path to a file for an attachment... but why not have the text in the email itself?  And that Logger method seems pointless... Can you be more specific about your question?  Are you asking about the architecture, the mailing method(s) or the logging method(s).  Also, where is the Selenium code here?  What is it you are logging?  Exceptions, or pass/fail conditions?

Comment: Hi, I've edited it again, basically what i need is to get those texts from Logger and assign it to the logFile variable.

Comment: When do you want to send the email with text file attachment? Only when exception occurs, when the code block ends, or some other condition?

Comment: @Ryan.Bartsch There is a mail.Send(); at the first part of the condition, but basically I need  to get every log texts everytime and pass it to a variable to be added as an attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netcore-3.1

You can use this function to create the text file at a specific location and write the required data to it.

Once you’ve written the text file with the necessary data you simply reference the path to the file to send it as an attachment.